# Word order in Indirect questions

Tags: sentence-structure

Which is right:

1. I would like to know when **exactly** the results will be posted.
2. I would like to know **exactly** when the results will be posted.
3. I would like to know when the results will be posted **exactly**.

Comment: These are all "right".  Which is "best" depends on which you think best fits the context.  It's personal writing style.

Comment: I would add that that #3 to me sounds the more strange than either 1 or 2.

Comment: Thank you very much.